# What is the difference between SMT test suite description and comment?

Tags: origen-sdk

I see the [SMT test suite has a 'comment' attribute](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/test_suite.rb#L9) and also see that [atp gem generally supports a test level description](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/atp/blob/master/lib/atp/flow_api.rb#L18).  Which should I use to add a line in the rendered SMT flow file?  The following does not work when called from [here](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/atp/blob/master/lib/atp/flow_api.rb#L20):

```
func :my_func, comment: "make a comment"
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A description is intended to be a meta-documentation of the test, meaning it is potentially long and not rendered to the generated program. Instead it would be used in documentation, that is outlined here - https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/doc/

This comment attribute directly maps to the comment field in the test program, it does not by default contain the description/documentation though you could probably set it up like that.

When [creating a test suite](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Creating_a_Test_Suite) the comment should be picked up. If you are not seeing it in the generated flow, then it probably means that your interface layer is not forwarding that comment option to the test suite creation.

So, either pass the options along when you are calling `test_suites.add`, or else set it in the test suite object like this: `my_test_suite.comment = options[:comment]`.

Comment: I was able to verify that passing `:comment` to the test suite creation method does not work (traced it into origen_testers and atp gems) but setting it after the test suite creation is done works.  Will try to fix the issue and submit a PR.  thx